# I want 3 sections of a row to be of different colors need help in CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to make 3 sections with different colors, left and right sections should be blue and the middle one should be red. The website is on WordPress so I am trying to put css code into visual composer but not able to find the perfect css code. 
Here's what I am currently using:

```
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #b12223 , #b12223 49.999999%, #088 50%, #088);
    }
```

But the above code is totally different from what I am trying to do.

[Here is an example screenshot of what I am trying to do:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3P7v.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use nth-child selector of css to give background to your containers.

```
.container:nth-child(1) {
    background: #F58320;
}
.container:nth-child(2) {
    background: #86C140;
}
.container:nth-child(3) {
    background: #2AABE1;
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. I have just added you code but I see white background behind all the sections.

Comment: Please check if you are using the correct class name in css. It should be .container not .containers.